# VS Code: Japanese and lineHighlightBackground

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors

I'm dressing up VS Code.

I found to editor.lineHighlightBackground.

I decided to leave a comment in case I get dementia. But, Japanese text is *×always* **○typing** highlighted.(I edit this line)

And, the clarity will probably be doubled.

Can I adjust the Japanese highlighting?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s7QM.png).

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT7jo.png).

These were not work.
Unicode Highlight
editor.renderLineHighlight
editor.selectionHighlightBackground

[This question was also posted issues of vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/202700)

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#ffff0044",
            //"こんにちは！おはようaあaあ" ←Happen this ploblem
    },
    "editor.renderLineHighlight": "gutter",
}
```

Add more

```
バージョン: 1.85.1 (user setup)
コミット: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
日付: 2023-12-13T09:49:37.021Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. please add a [mre]: a minimal settings file that reproduces this issue. make sure you don't also have workspace settings on top of user settings that are also customizing occurrences highlighting.

Comment: @starball Sorry, I added code.  Does this correspond to occurrences highlighting?

Comment: does this reproduce when not using portable mode? I can't reproduce this issue in non-portable mode. also, you still have not edited your question post to address my first comment.

Comment: @starball Strangely, I had skipped over the first question, sorry.
I was going to use portable mode to reset extensions and settings. I thought this serves the same purpose as ```Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled"```...

The above is the installation version information. This problem occurs in any case.
Also, this occurs for typing characters only.

What I find strange is why when I start typing Japanese, ``lineHighlightBackground`` is attached to this.

Comment: hm. I'd suggest that you also raise a bug ticket by using the Help > Raise Issue menu item. If you do, please add a link here to your issue ticket.

Comment: Does this mean I need to post the same question again on strackoverflow? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: no. the menu item I'm referring to is in _VS Code_'s UI- not stackoverflow.

Comment: I posted https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/202700. thank.